Where is this verse cited in the commentary on the Bhagavata purana?
https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/4/30/36/

yas tu nārāyaṇaṁ devaṁ


brahma-rudrādi-daivataiḥ


samatvenaiva vīkṣeta


sa pāṣaṇḍī bhaved dhruvam


“One who considers Lord Nārāyaṇa on a level with great demigods like Lord Brahmā and Lord Śiva is immediately listed among nonbelievers.”

This is similar to the story of Nampaduvan in the Srivaishnavite tradition
According to Sri Vaishnavism, what happens to someone who worships someone other than Lord Vishnu as Brahman?

This verse is mentioned in Caitanya Caritamrita Madhya 18:116

yas tu nārāyaṇaṁ devaṁ brahma-rudrādi-daivataiḥ samatvenaiva vīkṣeta
sa pāṣaṇḍī bhaved dhruvam
TRANSLATION “‘A person who considers demigods like Brahmā and Śiva to
be on an equal level with Nārāyaṇa is to be considered an offender, or
pāṣaṇḍī.’”

And also repeated in CC Madhya 25:80

what about the person who cosideres equal qualities to lord himself in moksha.. is he also not a pasandi this belief of jiva equal in any aspect should be condemn even in moksha

Is the ultimate source Chaitanya or is Chaitanya citing something from Canonical scripture? @CracklingCyclone

@SK CC doesn't cite any scriptures, so obviously it was his own quote
